# How to use confirmCardSetup Method Stripe, for multiples Elements. Laravel Cashier / Vue App

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

How to send inputs separately from stripe, through the confirmCardSetup method, since the documentation only receives one cardElement element.

https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup -> documentation.

I was researching around here, and other sites on the Internet, and found these components separately, but currently, I'm working with a setup token attempt that comes from the backend, as I can send all these elements separately to the endpoint that provides me with the documentation.

https://prnt.sc/toyr9n -> **My currents Elements**

https://prnt.sc/toyrmt -> **My Stripe endpoint implementation.**

Note: How can I make a custom form for stripe, without having to use the cardElement, or manipulate the inputs separately.

I would be very grateful for your responses, and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using split elements, Stripe.js will automatically infer all the elements needed by just passing in one element.

In your case, you can just pass in the `cardNumber` element when confirming your SetupIntent and Stripe.js will find all the other elements and evaluate those automatically.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, you know some way to get the values ​​of the fields that are filled, is for customizing an animation, but since it is embedded and it makes sense for security reasons, I cannot get this data.

Comment: It's not possible to get the contents of the Elements field by design, as that would mean you have access to the sensitive data (you not having access is the whole point of Elements for PCI reasons). Best you can do is listen to the 'change' event to see if the input is valid or not: https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/input_validation